# What is a good generic strategy for playing as Geralt?

Tags: the-witcher-adventure-game

In the [Witcher Adventure Game](https://thewitcher.com/en/adventuregame), you can play as one of four characters trying to complete a set of quest. Geralt is clearly a monster slayer and as such should pick quests form the combat desk.

*Is there a good generic strategy that can be applied to Geralt?*

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1484/5318)